# Why are my foreign keys not showing up when I view my db on a db browser? Am I entering them wrong?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

```
    package com.example.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //making db and setting tables 1-6 names
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE1_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final String TABLE2_NAME = "Uinfo";
    private static final String TABLE3_NAME = "exercises";
    private static final String TABLE4_NAME = "calories";
    private static final String TABLE5_NAME = "calendar";
    // private static final String TABLE6_NAME = "settings";

    //these are for table 1
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    //for table 2
    private static final String COLUMN_ID2 = "id2";
    private static final String COLUMN_AGE = "age";
    private static final String COLUMN_WEIGHT = "weight";
    private static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "height";
    private static final String COLUMN_SEX = "sex";
    private static final String COLUMN_FK_CONTACTS_ID = "id";
    // private static final String COLUMN_FK_SETTINGS_ID = "id_6";
    private static final String COLUMN_FK_CALENDAR_ID = "id5";

 //creating tables
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE1_NAME +
            " (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null ," +
            " name text not null , " +
            " email text not null ," +
            " pass text not null, " +
            " uname text not null);";

    private static final String TABLE2_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE2_NAME +
            "(id2 integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null ," +
            " age text not null , " +
            " weight text not null ," +
            " height text not null, " +
            " sex text not null, " +
            " FOREIGN KEY ("+ COLUMN_ID2 +") REFERENCES  "+TABLE1_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID+")," +
            " FOREIGN KEY ("+ COLUMN_ID2 +") REFERENCES  "+TABLE5_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID5+"));";
    //" FOREIGN KEY ("+ COLUMN_ID2 +") REFERENCES  "+TABLE6_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID6+"));";
```

basically the foreign keys don't show up in the db when viewing it.
I've tried adding in

```
"id integer not null"
```

before the first foreign key line and that made the database stop writing data to that table. I've updated the database version to see if that would make a difference too, but to no avail.
Am I calling it wrong? I could just be missing the correct way to write in the column the foreign key goes into. Though I'm not sure how it would be inserted the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is a misunderstanding of what the FOREIGN KEY .... clause does.

It does not create a column for storing the foreign key. Rather it adds a constraint (a rule) that says that the column(s) in the table being created **MUST** contain an existing value in the table(columns) specified after REFERENCES.

The statements are correct and actually do create the Foreign Key constraints; as will be shown.

Consider the following (taken by running the code using Android Studio that you have supplied (plus code to make it usable) and thus creating the database and the tables needed)

- using DEBUG to stop when creating the Uinfo table (as well as the other tables) and copying the value from the TABLE2_CREATE variable the value obtained is :-

  - `create table Uinfo(id2 integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null , age text not null ,  weight text not null , height text not null,  sex text not null,  FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES  contacts(id), FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES  calendar(id5));`

Dropping this value into an SQLite tool (navicat) and then running the following SQL:-

```
create table contacts (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null , name text not null ,  email text not null , pass text not null,  uname text not null);
CREATE TABLE calendar(id5 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,other TEXT);
create table Uinfo(id2 integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null , age text not null ,  weight text not null , height text not null,  sex text not null,  
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES  contacts(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES  calendar(id5));


SELECT * FROM Uinfo;
INSERT INTO Uinfo VALUES(null,10,5.6,70,'Female');
```

Results in :-

[image]

Clearly the INSERT did not insert the data. A look at the log shows:-

```
create table Uinfo(id2 integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null , age text not null ,  weight text not null , height text not null,  sex text not null,  
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES  contacts(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES  calendar(id5))
> OK
> Time: 0.074s


SELECT * FROM Uinfo
> OK
> Time: 0s


INSERT INTO Uinfo VALUES(null,10,5.6,70,'Female')
> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
> Time: 0s
```

So the foreign key constraint has been added.

Doing the equivalent in the testing Android App was undertaken using the code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Uinfo VALUES(null,10,5.6,70,'Female')");
        Log.d("DBINFO","After the first insert");
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = true");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Uinfo VALUES(null,10,5.6,70,'Female')");
        Log.d("DBINFO","After the second insert");
    }
}
```

results in :-

```
2021-04-24 15:34:27.954 5644-5644/a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing D/DBINFO: After the first insert
2021-04-24 15:34:27.955 5644-5644/a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-04-24 15:34:27.957 5644-5644/a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing, PID: 5644
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing/a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:748)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1770)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
        at a.a.so67224090javafknotshowing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The App has crashed with an exception, the exception message being **`FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)`**

**BUT** the log also contains **`D/DBINFO: After the first insert`**.

i.e. the first INSERT did not cause the exception, it was the second after THE IMPORTANT  `db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = true");`

Without this line (or an equivalent) then the default on Android (as it is with the default SQLite) is that Foreign Key processing is turned off. The above turns Foreign Key processing on.

So if you issue is more that the foreign keys do nothing then this could be the cause.